# Can anyone help me correct this sentence?

Tags: grammatical-number, vocabulary, present-perfect

> Have you ever met any ghosts?

And I was suggested to correct it as follow:

> Have you seen any ghosts?

So my questions are:

1. What is the difference between using the 'ever' in this sentence or not using it? Are both of them correct?
2. Do I need to make the word after 'any' as plural if they are countable nouns? Are there any other circumstances when I have to use single pattern of nouns after 'any'? How to decide the different application?
3. Why should I replace 'met' with 'seen'?

Comment: [It was suggested that I correct.] Usually, one talks of seeing ghosts, not meeting them. Though you could use meet in the sense of run into at a place. I met a ghost on the footpath to the sea.

Comment: The difference between met and seen is the same whether it used with “a ghost” or “a policeman”.  Whether or not one believes it’s possible to see or meet a ghost is immaterial to the grammaticality of the question.

Answer (score 2):

To a large degree it's just personal choice, and picking an appropriate "tone" for the context.

The choice of using "ever" or not depends on the precise meaning you're seeking.  If you use "ever" then the implication is that you want to know if any time in their life the person has encountered a ghost, whereas if you "ever" (and don't replace it with a similar term) the question *might* be interpreted to be asking if you've seen a ghost during the current ghost hunting expedition on some such.

The choice between "met" and "seen" depends on how close the encounter is.  Frank may have "seen" a ghost a half mile away, but Joe came within a few feet of a ghost and they demonstrated some awareness of each other -- he "met" the ghost.